# Разделение данных по дням/месяцам

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Подскажите способы группировки данных по дням/месяцам

Суть такая: мне в теле запроса приходит параметр, который указывает, как разбивать данные(по дням/месяцам), плюс интервал дат (начальная дата + конечная дата), на выходе я должен получить что то вроде такого:

```
[
(данные за первый день/месяц),
(данные за второй день/месяц),
... и т.д.
]
```

Надеюсь, смог донести мысль

Comment: Добавьте информации: откуда Вы собираете данные, есть ли в данных какая-то информация о днях/месяцах, ...

Comment: Нужен пример входных данных и пример того, что должно быть на выходе в соответствии с этими входными данными. в противном случае это - "лечение по фотографии".